# kernel panic error when trying to load bootpimage with hardware monitoring enabled

Tags: linux

when i enable hardware monitoring from makemenuconfig and try to load bootpimage i get the following error. we are doing this for an arm based processor

Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!